# Building Terraform Custom Variables when using Count for AWS Lambda Functions

Tags: variables, aws-lambda, count, terraform

I am trying to generate a variable for a Lambda Function that is based on the setting from an API Gateway created at the same time using Terraform.  I am using trimprefix and trimsuffix to modify the setting I get from the api gateway, which I then set as an Environment Variable to be used by the Lambda Function Code.

I had this working initially using output statements as I was originally using modules.  I have since decided to move away from modules to simplify the code.  However my real issue is how do I perform the trimprefix and trimsuffix actions when I am also using the count feature.

Here is my original code when I was still using modules, and it successfully created the final "invoke_url" after trimming "https://" from the beginning, and "/default" from the end.

```
## Obtain the rest_api_id
output "rest_api_id" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.retaildiscount[count.index].rest_api_id
}

## Trim the https prefix from the invoke URL and store in var.invoke_url_tmp
output "invoke_url_tmp" {
  value = trimprefix(aws_api_gateway_deployment.retaildiscount[count.index].invoke_url, "https://")
}

## Trim the /default suffix from var.invoke_url_tmp and output as var.invoke_url to be used
## by the retailorderprice function
output "invoke_url" {
  value = trimsuffix(var.invoke_url_tmp, "/default")
}
```

I am now trying to do the same, but when using "count" to create multiple copies of the same Lambda Functions and API Gateways (this is to create multiple instances for a lab style workshop, each Function will have a unique name pulled from a aito.tfvars file

For the life of me I cannot work out how to generate the modified variable and link it back to the appropriate function

Comment: Can I ask why you need the invoke URL inside the Lambda function that is being invoked by the API Gateway?